# presentViewController on iPhone5 with iOS6 presents landscape view 460px wide instead of 568px

Tags: iphone, ios6

I hope someone can help:

I have ported my App for the iPhone 5. All Views are Landscape only and I set the width to be 568 pixels in IB. When the App starts the main view is displayed correctly with full width. But when I call the SettingsView using presentViewController it is displayed with 460 pixels / 3.5" mode. When I dismiss the SettingsView, then the Toolbar of the main View  now also is shrunk to 460 pixels. However the Graphics which I draw are still 568 pixels wide.

I did a NSLog(@"%f", self.view.frame.size.width) in the Controller's viewDidLoad method of the Settings view and it outputs 568.0 which means the view itself "knows" that it is 568 wide. Still it is displayed with only 460px.

And here's the code - nothing fancy though....

```
- (IBAction) showSettingsView 
{
     FlipsideViewController *controller = [[FlipsideViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FlipSideView" bundle:nil];
     controller.delegate = self;

     controller.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;

     [self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil]  ;

     [controller release];
}


- (void)flipsideViewControllerDidFinish:(id)controller
{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil] ;
}
```

I have posted the same question on the Apple develop forum, but did not get an answer yet:
[enter link description here](https://devforums.apple.com/message/733649)

This happens on iPhone 5 device and in the simulator.
Any ideas?

Comment: Answering my own question:

Just got the solution on the Apple Developer board.

Solution: I had to set the MainWindow in MainWindow.xib to "Full Screen at Launch" and simulated Metrics size to "Retina 4 Full Screen".

Comment: Please post your comment as an actual answer so the question may be closed.

Answer (score 1):

Set the MainWindow in MainWindow.xib to "Full Screen at Launch" and simulated Metrics size to "Retina 4 Full Screen".

Comment: @user1694772 - now u can close the ques

Answer (score 1):

If you are not using xib for `UIWindow`, but using xibs for ViewController's view

```
_settingsController = [[CNPSettingsViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"CNPViewController" bundle:nil];
[_settingsController setDelegate:self];
[_settingsController setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal];

//this line solved the problem for me
[_settingsController.view setBounds:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
```